# Add enctype in jquery form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var form = $('<form/>', {
    action: 'SupportRequest', 
    method: 'POST', 
    name: 'myForm', 
    id: 'myForm'
}).appendTo('body');
```

I have to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` manually during form creation, how do i do this so that the above code looks like

```
<form class="hidden" id="myForm" mrthod="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="myservlet">
```

and also please tell me how to make it of class='hidden' manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add them to the parameters of the object you already provide:

```
var form = $('<form/>', {
    action: 'SupportRequest', // this should be 'myservlet' to match the HTML you gave
    method: 'POST', 
    name: 'myForm', 
    id: 'myForm',
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    class: 'hidden'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Comment: This is a different question but related, what if i want to add input of type file to this form. How do i do it? i was using      form.append("<input type='hidden' name='graph1' id='graph1' value=''/>");         and was adding value using    $('#graph1').val(graph1);    How can i do this for file to get something like  <input type="file" name = "file1"> in the form

Comment: But i get an error that says angular.min.js:62 Error: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string, the file is'nt sent to servlet by putting the name of the file inside value.

Comment: Ah yes, you can only get the value of a file input. You cannot set it at all. This is a security restriction of JS

Comment: For a file input, it's not possible. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single string containing all the necessary markup and inject it using jQuery.

```
var htmlForm = '<form class="hidden" id="myForm" mrthod="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" action="myservlet">';
$("body").append(htmlForm);
```